# Deleting test executions in test plan using REST API

Tags: jira-xray

so i'm trying to figure out how to implement some sort of retention policy in Xray JIRA for test executions, i.e. deleting all test executions past some certain date. The plan is to implement an external application to periodically (maybe once a day) check and delete test executions satisfied by a policy.

However, I tried using the REST API for deleting test executions (https://confluence.xpand-it.com/display/public/XRAY/Test+Plans+-+REST) but it is only disassociating the test execution with the test plan and it is not really deleted. Is deleting a test execution entry not available in Xray JIRA REST API?

I am open to suggestions as well regarding the retention policy if there is another way to do it, since I can't seem to find any documentation if it is supported natively in Xray JIRA.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution,
I used the native JIRA REST API for deleting issues

> DELETE /rest/api/2/issue/{testExecutionKey}

Reference: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/#api-rest-api-2-issue-issueIdOrKey-delete